chrome window.open onload handler
I'm executing the following (modified for demo) script in the console of x.com
There is no cross-domain issues. But the function executes immediately - which results in an error because the DOM is not loaded (I can see visually).
If I set a timeout setTimeout(parsefn,9000) (ensuring dom is loaded), it works fine.
If I execute newWindow.onload() after dom load, it works fine.
Reading stackoverflow and what not - indicates the code should be working ... ? How do I get the code to work - that is execute the function when the child window dom is loaded.
On the latest version of Chrome browser.
let newWindow;
function tweetGet(url) {
  newWindow = window.open(url,'_blank',"status,heigh​t=600,width=800");
  const parsefn = function(event) {
    const tweet = [url];
    tweet.push(newWindow.document.querySelectorAll("time")[0].getAttribute("datetime"));
    newWindow.close();
    console.log(tweet);
  }
  newWindow.document.body.onload = parsefn; 
}
tweetGet("https://x.com/VillaCollegeMv/status/1817893326437425374")


You say there's no crossdomain issues, but I don't see how you could ever read from the DOM on a different origin.

As stated above, the code is executed on the javascript console of "x.com" and it opens a link that is on "x.com" - it opens it fine. no issues. NO cross domain issues.

Ah I missed that. Have you considered this even: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Yes. Tried earlier and as expected same result. Expected because "load" event comes after the "DOMContentLoaded"

So one theory I would have is that Twitter might have an SPA like UI and they actually do a bunch of work with Javascript before rendering the UI.

Is there an event for that?
At the conclusion of all javascript execution and dom rendering?

There is not. A lot of this is happening asynchronously. Some applications never stop 'doing work'
